# Shiny quickly shows the selected input but reverts back to first input

Tags: r, shiny

Everything is loading fine, but whenever I choose Watts, Volts or Amps, the Dygraph chart quickly reverts back to graphing the Scan channel.  The Wattage, Voltage and Amp charts quickly show, but then it reverts back to the Scan input.

Any ideas on how I can make it stop reverting back to the Scan channel and keep it on the Channel that I choose?

[My dataset is here for you to upload.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzg7bDcyZobbQ1RqTmpUSFVQMGM/view)
ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Engineering Data",             
tabPanel("Upload your Own File:",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          tags$hr(),
                          checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                       c(Comma=',',
                                         Semicolon=';',
                                         Tab='\t'),
                                       ','),
                          radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                       c(None='',
                                         'Double Quote'='"',
                                         'Single Quote'="'"),
                                       '"'),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels", label = "Choose Channel",
                                         choices = NULL)
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                              dygraphOutput('graph')
                        ))



                        )

                               )))
```

server.R

```
output$graph <- renderDygraph({
    uploadedFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(uploadedFile))
      return(NULL)

    # Clean up the loaded CSV File, convert Time column to a Time Object for Dygraph.
    uploadedFile <- read.csv(uploadedFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
                             quote=input$quote)
    uploadedFile$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))
    uploadedFile$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # Update the SelectInput and store the value in component5 to be used in the graph.

    observeEvent(uploadedFile, {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels', choices = names(uploadedFile))
    })
    selectedInput <- input$uploadChannels
    component5 <- uploadedFile[, selectedInput]


    xts(component5, uploadedFile$Time)  %>%
      dygraph()
     })

})
```

Comment: may be you need to use `observeEvent(uploadedFile, {` outside of `renderDygraph({` ? because when you try to plot choises changed and you need to plot again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Batanichek was correct.  I had to modify `server.R` and it now works!
Please note that I added a second input, so that is why the commands are doubled.

```
  uploadedFile1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file1, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file1)) return(NULL)"
    uf1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })
  uploadedFile2 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file2, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file2)) return(NULL)"
    uf2 <- read.csv(input$file2$datapath)
  })

  observeEvent(uploadedFile1(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels1', choices = names(uploadedFile1()))
  })
  observeEvent(uploadedFile2(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels2', choices = names(uploadedFile2()))
  })

  output$graph <- renderDygraph({


    # Clean up the loaded CSV File, convert Time column to a Time Object for Dygraph.
    uploadedFile1 <- uploadedFile1()
    uploadedFile2 <- uploadedFile2()

    uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))
    uploadedFile2$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile2$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))

    uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile1$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    uploadedFile2$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile2$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # Update the SelectInput and store the value in component5 to be used in the graph.
    selectedInput1 <- input$uploadChannels1
    selectedInput2 <- input$uploadChannels2
    component5 <- uploadedFile1[, selectedInput1]
    component6 <- uploadedFile2[, selectedInput2]
    cbinded <- cbind(component5, component6)

    xts(cbinded, uploadedFile1$Time, uploadedFile2$Time)  %>% 
      dygraph()

    })
```